# Magento 2 nginx 404 eror

Tags: magento2, php, url, nginx

I am attempting to open a php file by pointing the path in the url.

**First** 
I add the testfile.php in the pub fodler since that is the root folder specified in `nginx.conf.sample`

**Second** 
I edit `nginx.conf.sample` around line 109 from this:

```
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check)\.php$ {
```

to

```
location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503|health_check|testfile)\.php$ {
```

**Third**
Execute:
 `sudo service nginx reload`

I can access files like .txt .jpg but not files like php by entering www.mywebsite.net/testfile.txt

Why I still can't open the testfile.php?

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to test the configuration file, but `nginx.conf.sample` is probably just an example file, the real configuration file should be called `nginx.conf`.

Comment: If you want to execute that file then you can run via command line. Asummed you have kept test.php in root folder then you can run like : php test.php